# Finding the series using Recursion

Tags: java, recursion

I am trying to print 122333221 using recursion if n is 3.But i am not able to solve it.We have given the number we have to print the series using recursion.For example if n = 3 then it should print 122333221.

```
public static void print(int n){
if(n < 1 ){
  return;
}

print(n-1);
for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++){
    System.out.print(n);
}

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
print(3);

}
```

Comment: Seems like a good time to grab a pen and paper and write down what you want each recursive call of the function to do. The current definition of your function is problematic.

Comment: Yes.For 4 it should print 1223334444333221

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use the normal technique of keeping track of your state through parameters by defining a `public` method which uses a `private` method with extra parameters.

```
// Repeats n n times.
private static void repeat(int n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        System.out.print(n);
    }
}

private static void print(int n, int v) {
    if (n == v) {
        // Just once for the deepest level.
        repeat(n);
    } else {
        // Wrap the inner print ...
        repeat(n);
        // Recurse with the next higher value.
        print(n + 1, v);
        // ... end the wrap.
        repeat(n);
    }
}

public static void print(int n) {
    System.out.print(n+": ");
    print(1, n);
    System.out.println();
}

public void test(String[] args) {
    for (int i = 1; i <= 9 ; i++) {
        print(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice solution. I think ``if (n > v) return;`` is reduntant.

Comment: @OldeCurmudgeon, don't see anything weird. ``n == v`` is the base case. ``n > v`` will never be true anyway.

Answer (score 0):

a possible solution will be n is the number of the different digits you have , while you need to print each digit times its value, so if n = 1

result =1

n =2 result 1221

n = 3, result 122333221

n = 4, result 1223334444333221

The implemenation is not hard , the base case is the number = n and its printed n times and you always print recursivly unless you reached n, the first call is always

```
solve(n, 1,1);
```

The implementation:

```
public void solve(int n, int numberOfPrints, int  num) {

if(numberOfPrints == 0 && n ==num )
return ;
if(numberOfPrints == 0 )
   solve(n, num+1,num+1);

System.out.print(num);
solve(n, numberOfPrints-1, num);
if(num == n)
return;
System.out.print(num);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void PrintSeries(int seriesNum, int currentNum, bool movingForward)
{
       if(movingForward && currentNum < seriesNum)
       {

                 PrintNum(currentNum);
                 PrintSeries(seriesNum, currentNum + 1, true); 

       }
       else if(movingForward && currentNum == seriesNum)
       {

                 PrintNum(currentNum);
                 PrintSeries(seriesNum, currentNum - 1, false); 
       }
       else
       {
            if(currentNum > 0)
            {
                 PrintNum(currentNum);
            }

            if(currentNum - 1 > 0)
            {

                PrintSeries(seriesNum, currentNum - 1, false); 
            }
       }

}

public static void PrintNum(int num)
{
       for(int x = 0; x < num; x++)
       {
           System.out.print(num);
       }

}
```

Comment: PrintSeries is your recursive function, seriesNum parameter is "n", or the max number of the series, currentNum is the current number to print, and boolean movingForward alerts the function whether to check to terminate the recursion. To cut back on duplicate code, I made another void function called PrintNum, it takes a parameter of type int, it does a for loop which prints the number equal to itself. @notyou, that a good enough explanation?